# Perl Dancer: Getting data from forms

Tags: forms, perl, cgi, dancer

I'm a Perl newbie and would like to know:

- How can I use data from html forms with Perl dancer?

I'm struggling with the following example. I have a form on my `index.tt` file like this:

```
 <form action="/hello/:username" method="get" name="">
        <h3>Please log in </h3>
          <input type="text" name="username" required=""/>
          <input type="password" name="senha" required=""/>               
          <button name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit">Login</button>              
    </form>
```

I would like to use the username from the form and build a page which returns the typed information. So I've checked [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Tutorial.pod#Layouts) tutorial and I've done the following in my `Proyecto.pm`:

```
package Proyecto;
use Dancer ':syntax';
our $VERSION = '0.1';    


get '/' => sub {
template 'index';
};

get '/hello/:username' => sub {
my $username= params('username');
return "Hola $username";
};
```

But it doesn't work. Do you guys know what it's missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="/hello/:username" method="get" name="">
```

will call exactly `/hello/:username` without and replacement. HTML is unable to magically replace parts of the sourcecode - no matter if the backend is using Dancer or anything else. (JavaScript could do that.)

```
get '/hello/:username' => sub {
```

matches all calls to `/hello/` followed by any string, like `/hello/chungel`, `/hello/Larry` or `/hello/:username`. the last one would set the value `username` into `param('username')`.

You also added a form field with `name="username"` which ends up in two values for one key (one from the URL, one from the form).

Finally: Use a fixed URL as form action:

```
<form action="/hello" method="get" name="">
```

and

```
get '/hello' => sub {
```

Passing the username as HTML form value (and HTTP argument) doesn't get any advantage here.

If you really want to have the username within the URL, first use a different name in the route definition:

```
get '/hello/:url_username' => sub {
    return param('url_username');
```

Next you need to either rewrite the form action using JavaScript or rewrite the target URL using [a Dancer `before` hook](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#hook).

Comment: My edit-summary was supposed to be "please don't use CPAN links to specific versions, unless it's specifically about that version"

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Copied this one instead of using `perldoc?`.

Comment: If you prefer search.cpan.org to metacpan, you can use the permalink button in the top right, which gives `http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dancer`

Comment: @This the link was to an anchor, so that one probably doesn't work.